# Books on Celestial Mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, resource-recommendations, celestial-mechanics

My background is mathematics. I would like to study *celestial* (**not** classical) mechanics and looking for an appropriate book.

I found that somebody has already asked a similar question "[How to learn celestial mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35306/how-to-learn-celestial-mechanics)", but let me ask more specific question: Is there any textbook on celestial mechanics which contains **lots of figures** and is **of mathematical flavor**?

I don't need too elementary book; the level should be graduate math level. At the same time, a textbook without figures often makes it difficult for me to continue reading it.

Any suggestions/recommendations are welcome :-)

Comment: "Lots of figures" and "being of mathematical flavor" are rarely coincidental. Celestial mechanics is a simple application of mechanics. Unless you want to be a spacecraft navigator or are interested in a few limited questions about the stability of the solar system, there isn't much meat here, certainly not for a person with math background (cough).

Comment: Hi Anfisa,  Welcome to Phys.SE.  Res. recom. questions are restricted on Phys.SE because they tend to be _too broad_  _primarily opinion-based_ list questions. I'm closing this list question as a _duplicate,_ not because it is an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.